# How can I give focus to an Outlook folder picker that I called over a tkinter GUI?

Tags: python, tkinter, outlook, win32com, office-automation

I am programming a GUI with python tkinter to download all attachments from an Outlook folder to a directory.

I am wrapping `outlook.PickFolder` in a function that is also in another module than my GUI.
`outlook.PickFolder` allows me to pick the folder of my Outlook account.

```
import win32com.client

def getAtts(outlookfolderpath: str, savefolder: Path):
    outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch('Outlook.Application').GetNameSpace('MAPI')
    rootfolder = outlook.Folders.item(1)

    fold = outlook.PickFolder()
```

When I call this function the `PickFolder` dialog opens, but it is not given focus over other opened windows.

How is it possible to give focus, such that the dialog is on top of the other windows when called?

Answer (score 1):

The Outlook object model doesn't provide any method or property for bringing the dialog to the front. However, before calling the `PickFolder` method you may bring the Outlook windows to the front by calling the [Activate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.explorer.activate(method)) method which activates an explorer window by bringing it to the foreground and setting keyboard focus. After that you may try to call the `PickFolder` method.

Another possible workaround is to use Windows API methods for bringing dialog to the foreground. See [SetForegroundWindow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setforegroundwindow) for more information.

Note, a Folder object that represents the folder that the user selects in the dialog box is returned or `Nothing/null`if the dialog box is canceled by the user.